# How can I define foreign key routes in Flourish?

Tags: php, routes, flourishlib

I am using PHP with Flourish. I read their documentation [here](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fActiveRecord#CreatingandLoadingRecords) and [here](http://flourishlib.com/docs/OrmConventions#RelationshipRoutes). Let's suppose I have a table `persons` and another table `items`. Let's suppose further that I have an `item_id1` and an `item_id2` in the `persons` table. Both of them are foreign keys to the `items` table. I would like to get a record from the `items` table based on the relation between `persons` and `items` based on the `item_id2` foreign key.

If I am not mistaken this could be achieved with

```
$person->createItem()
```

if `$person` is the `fActiveRecord` generated from a record of the `persons` table in most of the cases. But in this particular case, when multiple foreign keys point to the very same table. This is understandable, because `Flourish` is not able to determine which relation should be used if we do not give it at least a route.

So, if we want to get the record from the items table which corresponds to the `item_id2` foreign key, then we should give the route as parameter. I didn't see a description or an example in their documentation which addresses this particular problem, so my question is:

How should we tell `createItem` that I want to use the `item_id2` key?

```
$person->createItem("item_id2")
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, your example should work. I just checked and I can tell that it works for me. The only difference I can spot between your example and the documentation is, that you are using double quotes. Try single quotes.

```
$person->createItem('item_id2')
```

I think that might be all it takes to make it work.

Comment: I do not believe that there is a difference between single and double quotes. They are both string representation in PHP. Why should simple quotes be better in this case?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't analyse this problem from an academic point of view. What I did is: I use the same function, it works for me and the only difference between your code and mine is the quotes.

Comment: But that does not make a difference, see the php documentation.